# How to convert text file with data that has missing placerholders into CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert text file into CSV file, but text file data contains missing placeholders such as below

- "-" is divider

```
apple - red - sweet - fruit - apple pie    
carrot - orange - - vegetable - carrot cake     
eggplant - purple - watery- vegetable -
```

```
import cvs
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in file)
    lines = (line.split("-") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('text.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('name', 'color', 'taste', 'category', 'recipe'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

What is the easiest way to deal with missing placeholders?

Comment: There's no way of knowing what field is missing without a human manually reading it.

Comment: 'name', 'color', 'taste', 'category', 'recipe'

Comment: Yes, I see that. But for `eggplant - purple - watery- vegetable`, how is the program supposed to know that `recipe` is missing? You and I can tell because we're human, and can associate the words to categories. The computer is not that smart.

Comment: I modified a little bit. They are separated by "-". so if it has empty space before, after or between "-". the machine can tell something is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
import csv

with open("data.txt", "r") as fin, open("data.csv", "w") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow(('name', 'color', 'taste', 'category', 'recipe'))
    writer.writerows(
        [item.strip() for item in row] for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter="-")    
    )
```

This is essentially swapping out `-` for `,` and stripping away whitespace.

Result for input file `data.txt`

```
apple - red - sweet - fruit - apple pie    
carrot - orange - - vegetable - carrot cake     
eggplant - purple - watery- vegetable -
```

is the file `data.csv` with the content

```
name,color,taste,category,recipe
apple,red,sweet,fruit,apple pie
carrot,orange,,vegetable,carrot cake
eggplant,purple,watery,vegetable,
```

Comment: Thank you. Also is there any way to detect and fill the blank if there's no separator and missing a value in a line?

Comment: @KojiE I don't quite understand your scenario: If there's no separator - here the `-` -,  or additional information, then the machine has no way of deciding where exactly the missing spot is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
allfood = []
s = '''apple - red - sweet - fruit - apple pie \
      carrot - orange - - vegetable - carrot cake     \
      eggplant - purple - watery- vegetable     '''
lines = s.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if line.count('-') == 3:
        line += '-'
    allfood.append([x.strip() for x in line.split('-')])
print(allfood)
```

Thanks.